# Setting read-only property from a method

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a simple problem, but I'm stuck as a newbie.

My `SetGrade` method takes a float parameter and I would like it to return a char
and then set that value to the Grade property.

I'm not doing something correctly.

```
public Class Student {
    private char grade;

    public char Grade { get { return grade; } }

    public char SetGrade(float score) {
        char Mgrade;
        if(score >= 90.0) {
            return Mgrade = 'A';
        }
        return Mgrade = 'F';
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `Mgrade` and why are you trying to assign to it? And why does your `Grade` property have a capital `P` in the access modifier? (C# is case-sensitive.)

Comment: Do you really only want to return `A` or `F` - or do you want to return "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" or "F" depending on `grade`?

Answer (score 15):

There are numerous problems with this code but they might not be what you think they are.

First off, `Public` is wrong; C# requires `public`.

Second, the use of the local `Mgrade` is strange and unnecessary, but interestingly enough not actually *wrong*; it is legal to do an assignment and a return in one step like that. But in this case you do not need to; just `return 'A';` without the local assignment.

Third, the method is misnamed because **it does not set the `Grade` property**. If you intend it to set the grade then it should be void returning:

```
public void SetGrade(float score)
{
   if(score >= 90.0)
   {
      this.grade = 'A';
   }
   this.grade = 'F';
}
```

If instead the method is intended to be a conversion from floats to chars then it should be static:

```
public static char ScoreToGrade(float score)
{
   if(score >= 90.0)
   {
      return 'A';
   }
   return 'F';
}
```

Frankly, I'd be inclined to do both:

```
public void SetGrade(float score)
{
  this.grade = ScoreToGrade(score);
}
```

There, now you've got the best of both worlds.

Fourth, this is just a stylistic point; you might consider:

```
  public char Grade { get; private set; }
```

the compiler will generate an "invisible" backing field for you, so you don't have to manage it yourself.  This syntax means that `Grade` can be read from anywhere and written to from within this class.

Comment: Ah i see! I indeed was intending to assign the Grade property. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 6):

No need to assign your character to an intermediate `char` variable. Just return correct character like this.

```
public char SetGrade(float score)
{
   if(score >= 90.0)
   {
      return 'A';
   }
   return 'F';
}
```

Comment: The entire function's content can even be simplified to `return score >= 90.0 ? 'A' : 'F'`;

Comment: @DavidS.: The code given is likely a simplified version of the real code.

Comment: @EricLippert absolutely, I just like pointing out things like that because I read a lot of unnecessarily long code around:)

Comment: Thanks guys. My problem is how to assign the Methods return value to the Grade property as it is a read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a bit off:

```
  public char SetGrade(float score)
  {
     if(score >= 90.0)
     {
       return 'A';
     }
     return 'F';
  }
```

No need for the `Mgrade` variable and you should simply return the character wanted, instead of an assignment and return.

Comment: @taras.roshko - If you mean that you can use the conditional operator, sure.

Comment: yes, but actually I agree with Eric that there are a lot of other issues in that code, including strange naming (or lack of prop assignment in SetGrade method)